# CodeIgniter .htaccess - 500 Internal Server Error/ index.php remove

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have a website like this (sub-domain)

```
rabbani.websolocom.xyz
```

And I have the `.htaccess` code like this (I used Codeigniter) :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /rabbani
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-D
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

But when I try to access my website it goes error (500 Internal Server Error). What should i do with my `.htaccess` file? Or any another file that wrong in my directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this

**[`.htaccess`](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html?highlight=url#removing-the-index-php-file)(Outside application folder)**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

> > This is Codeigniter recommended `.htaccess`

Answer (score 1):

Place the .htaccess inside the rabbani folder Like This

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[^./]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these two htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public_html/index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

And

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

More [htaccess here.](https://github.com/riwakawebsitedesigns/htaccess_for_codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

This is my new .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    # !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and leading
    #  slashes.
    # If your page resides at
    #  http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
    # then use
    # RewriteBase /mypage/test1/
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
if you are using codeigniter on local system

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /projectfolder/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /projectfolder/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

If you are using it on server then use this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for all of your answers sir :) but when i asked who has the hosting, he immediatly fixed my error. Changed my htaccess into his htaccess. I'll paste my new htaccess later