# how to remove index.php from codeigniter path

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

this is my wamp/www/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /project-name/index.php/$1 [L]

# Added a rewrite to respond with a 200 SUCCESS on every OPTIONS request
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
**strong text**
```

but error showing
The requested URL /ci/public/signup was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at ::1 Port 80
what is the problem.. i also remove index.php from config.php file..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess CodeIgniter - 500 Internal Server Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34714792/htaccess-codeigniter-500-internal-server-error)

Comment: then what to do now?

Comment: Or Even you can see the [documentation on Codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/codeigniter/929/getting-started-with-codeigniter/3068/installation-and-setup#t=201704031511502165007)

Comment: Before answer always check, **Is there duplicated Question** ..

Comment: and Read this too **[Codeigniter echoing ::1 instead of localhost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35876187/codeigniter-echoing-1-instead-of-localhost/35876229#35876229)**

Comment: but this is not an internal server error ....... error is Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at ::1 Port 80

Comment: chahe htaccess and check base url. go through the links

Comment: base url is empty

Comment: that's what i said go with the LINKS

Comment: kindly describe your answer... my baseurl is empty .. so what should i do with .htaccess file... this is my project file link............localhost/ci/public/signup

Comment: consider the `/project-name/` in regexps. `RewriteRule ^/?project-name/(.*)$ /project-name/index.php/$1 [L]`. Why the htaccess is not in the project dir.

Comment: There's a mismatch between `/project-name` and `/ci/public`.

Comment: You MUST provide the base_url in `application/config/config.php`. This needs to be done before you can work on any .htaccess issues. [Read this](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_303.html?highlight=base_url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTACCESS**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

Open config.php and do following replaces

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php"
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = ""
```

In some cases the default setting for uri_protocol does not work properly. Just replace

```
$config['uri_protocol'] ="AUTO"
```

by

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"
```

HTACCESS

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: @MuhammadAhsanAyazKhan try in another browser! This should work.

Comment: Note codeigniter 3 versions + do not have uri_protocol AUTO