# Removing index.php from codeigniter .htaccess on DigitalOcean

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, digital-ocean

Removing index.php from CodeIgniter `.htaccess` is not working on DigitalOcean. It's working fine on localhost though.

Comment: Try some of these https://github.com/wolfgang1983/htaccess_for_codeigniter

Comment: What is your current .htaccess?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter .htaccess - 500 Internal Server Error/ index.php remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34714792/codeigniter-htaccess-500-internal-server-error-index-php-remove)

Comment: This can _easily_ be closed as lacking an [mcve], since there is no detail for readers to respond to, nor any demonstration of effort.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the [Digitalocean documentation](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-htaccess-file), and look in the same page for the topic `How to Activate an .htaccess file`. That should makes your .htaccess setting working.