# unable to remove index.php from codeigniter url in live site

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I need to remove index.php from my codeigniter url. This is my code in .htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ /$1 [R=302,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

and modifications in config.php file :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/'
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

working fine in my localhost. but in my live site it generates a 404 error.

I can load the url with index.php ('http://example.com/index.php/Home'), but 'http://example.com/Home' generates 404 error. Why this only happens in live site? is there any other changes need?
one more thing, its not an apache server, my site is published in iis

Comment: try removing [R=302,L] from second line

Comment: only for live site? if i remove this from my code it will redirect to my dashboard in localhost

Comment: the site is published in IIS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter .htaccess - 500 Internal Server Error/ index.php remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34714792/codeigniter-htaccess-500-internal-server-error-index-php-remove)

Answer (score 0):

Paste the below code in your .htaccess file

```
   RewriteEngine On
   #RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1
```

then go to your config file in config folder and remove index.php from

```
   $config['index_page'] = '';
```

if you site is in the sub folder then you have to add the subfolder name after "#RewriteBase /"

Comment: its not in sub folder. so do i need to include RewriteBase ?

Comment: Yes indeed you do need add

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are missing

> RewriteBase /

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full htaccess which should be reside on main project folder. You have to write the rewritebase if it is on subfolder.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  # !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and leading
  #  slashes.
  # If your page resides at
  #  http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
  # then use
  # RewriteBase /mypage/test1/
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
  # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
  # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```